# htmlunit knockout js not working. Returning same page on clicking of submit button

Tags: java, knockout.js, htmlunit

I am new to htmlunit and need to do testing for a webpage which is written in htmlunit. There is no form in that login page.

Below is the html code for username, password and submit button -

```
<div class="loader-mask" data-bind="visible: false">
                    <div class="loader"> Loading Form...</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Email ID:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="user@company.com" data-bind="
                        value: loginHandler.userEmail,
                        enterKey: signIn
                    ">
                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Passwords are case-sensitive" data-bind="
                        value: loginHandler.userPassword,
                        enterKey: signIn
                    ">
                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                <div class="text-right">
                    <p><button type="button" id="qaSignIn" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="
                        click: signIn,
                        disable: loginHandler.isLoggingIn,
                        continueOn: userLoggedIn,
                        continueLink: { link: 'dashboard.html', params: {} }
                    ">
```

Now, in htmlunit, i am able to get username, password and button easily and I am able to set values for username and password field as well but when i am clicking on button, it's returning same html login page. I have tried logging in with credentials on the browser and I am able to login there. So credentials are good.

My htmlunit code is -

```
HtmlTextInput htmlInputUsername = (HtmlTextInput) loginPage.getElementByName("username");
htmlInputUsername.setValueAttribute("myUserName");
HtmlPasswordInput htmlInputPassword = (HtmlPasswordInput) loginPage.getElementByName("password");
htmlInputPassword.setValueAttribute("myPassword");
HtmlButton htmlButton = (HtmlButton) loginPage.getElementById("qaSignIn"); 
loginPage = htmlButton.click();
```

I tried printing page.asXml() before and after clicking on login button but its returning same xml page. Any idea what am i doing wrong? 
I have even tried setting these options -

```
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the url to analyze your page i can only guess.

At first try to enable javascript

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

At second

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000);
```

is not a option. Doing it during WebClient setup is useless. You have to place this call after your click

```
loginPage = htmlButton.click();
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000);
```

Maybe it is an option to use WETATOR (www.wetator.org) for your testing. Interaction with an web page is much simpler and all the wait magic is done automatically for you.

Comment: That helps. Thank you
but now next problem - When i login to the application in browser, I see submit button goes disabled for a while and then it redirects to next page. 

In our code, page returned from clicking the button has button as disabled and that's it. Nothing is happening after it. It's not re-directing to the next page.

Comment: One more thing i checked in my page, there are many scripts with <script type="text/html" and in htmlunit, this script is being skipped.
This method is being called internally - com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.isJavaScript(String typeAttribute, final String languageAttribute)

and typeAttribute is text/html and languageAttribute is empty when this method is called. 

As there is no support in the code to execute text/html, i am getting "Script is not JavaScript (type: text/html, language: ). Skipping execution" log statment

Any idea how such scripts can be executed?

Comment: Can you please switch to the latest HtmlUnit version - we did so many changes and we are not able to support that old versions.

Answer (score 0):

the js ajax may have such code "window.location.href"。then you should do like this code:

```
List<WebWindow> webWindows = client.getWebWindows();
WebWindow webWindow = webWindows.get(0);
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webWindow.getEnclosedPage();
```